# Importing from Excel to Access Key Violations and Identical Formatting

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

first of all I'd like to say thanks. Although I'm still pretty new to it, I've learned nearly everything I know about Access from this site. This is one of the most helpful forums I've ever used.

I'm having a problem importing data to my Access database from my Excel spreadsheet. I keep getting a key violation saying a particular field (column) in each row was deleted. I have two tables on my database and two coinciding sheets on my spreadsheet. Both sheets have this particular field. Sheet1 is importing fine, but Access won't import anything from that field on sheet2. All the properties for this field are the same and the data preview during import verifies that the data is coming from both sheets in the same form.

From this source: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Key-Violations-Append-Q-t1918322.html
Key violations occur for 3 reasons:

1) when the record you are attempting to add to the table adds a duplicate value where the field does not allow duplicates
- This can't be it because every value in the field is unique and the field is set to allow duplicate values. And my primary key is the Access-generated replication ID.

2) when the record has a field value that is null and the field in the table is a required field
- the field on sheet1 is adding null values, and not all the values on sheet2 that won't add are null value. and the fields are set to accept null values.

3) Where a value is added that is not in a related table and referential integrity is set on the link between the tables
- I have no relationships set in my database yet.

I have done this import successfully before a few times and I've only made minor changes since then, the majority of which on the Excel file. Thanks for any replies, and thanks very much for any explanations.

Comment: I had my replication ID as the first column in my table, I moved it to where it is now the last column on the table. Now it will let me copy-paste the data into the table but still no import. I would really like to be able to import directly since I'll be repeating the action many times, so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Things to check: Check the formatting of the Excel columns; are they numbers, dates, where they need to be, are the numbers in the right range; make sure there are no spaces in empty cells. Are the data-types in the tables suitable. Are there any validation rules in the table design causing conflict.

Comment: Checked and rechecked everything.The only other thing I can think of is to rebuild the sheet and the database

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good alternative solution to troubleshooting this problem. Instead of directly importing the data to the table I constructed in Access to match my Excel sheet, I imported the sheet by having Access create a new table. This table is automatically formatted to match the excel file that I am importing from.